# Django - What are the advantages and disadvantages of using unique_togueter vs. using a queryset in the view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Suppose we have the next model:

```
class Publications(models.Model):
     author = ..........
     post = ..........
```

and we don't want duplicate records to be stored in the database.

This could be done with unique togheter on the model:

```
 Meta:
    unique_together = (author, post)
```

or it could be done in the view with something like:

```
register_exist = Publications.objects.filter(...).exists()
if register_exist == False:
     #Code to save the info
```

**What are the advantages or disadvantages of using these methods?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
 Meta:
    unique_together = (author, post)
```

**Constrain at database level**. This make the data always consistent no matter what views input the data.

But the other one:

```py
register_exist = Publications.objects.filter(...).exists()
if register_exist == False:
     #Code to save the info
```

**Constrain at application level**. There might be a cost to query and check if the record is existing or not. And the data might not be consistent among the application when somebody might add new record without this step (by incident or accident), that make the data no longer consistent anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the [**`unique_together`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) attribute create a [**`UNIQUE` constraint**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint) whereas the [**`.filter(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter) is used to filter the `QuerySet` wrt the given conditions.
In other words, If you applied `unique_together` functionality in your model, you can't break that constraint (technically possible, but) even if you try to do so.